# Scatter plot and clusters within it

Tags: r, ggplot2, k-means, scatter-plot

I created a scatter plot using the [ggplot2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ggplot2) package for my data. Since my data has a large number of points, I will explain my problem with already available small dataset. Consider this scatter plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image: Scatter plot between wt and mpg]

I want to use [*k*-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) to cluster these data points, but then also show the clusters on the same scatter plot (the one shown above) and not a new dimensionality reduction plot? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative using `factoextra` package:

```
library(factoextra)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  select(x = wt, y = mpg)


# Compute k-means with k = 3

set.seed(123)
res.km <- kmeans(scale(df[, -5]), 3, nstart = 25)

res.km$cluster

fviz_cluster(res.km, data = df[, -5],
             palette = c("steelblue", "gold", "limegreen"), 
             geom = "point",
             ellipse.type = "convex", 
             ggtheme = theme_bw()
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse` to draw some ellipses around your clusters:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

km.mtcars <- kmeans(scale(mtcars), centers = 3)

mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$cluster = km.mtcars$cluster

ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = factor(cluster)))
```

[image]

Comment: can we also get the data based on points that belong to it's cluster?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "data based on points that belong to it's cluster"?

Comment: like have a table where it shows cluster 3 blue belongs to these points and so on..

Comment: In general yes. Not sure how you would your table to look like. But as I added the cluster to the dataframe you could of course create a table showing which e.g. cars belong to which cluster.